# Writing HTML code for table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am learning to work with JavaScript and I am trying to create a HTML table in the script, with values from a function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript">
function nextStep(xn, a) {
 var xn1 = (xn+(a/xn)/2);
 return xn1;
}

function getError(xn, a) {
 var err = xn-(a/xn);
 return err;
}

function newtonRoot(x) {
if(x>0) {
 var a = 2;
 var error = getError(x, a);
 var zeilen = 0;
 var x_werte = [];
 var errors = [];

 while(error>0.0001) {
 x = nextStep(x, a);
 error = getError(x, a);
 zeilen++;
 x_werte[zeilen] = x;
 errors[zeilen] = error;
 }
 var ergebnis = x;
 const GLOBAL_ERROR = error;

 document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("<table border=" + "1" + ">"));
 document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("<tr><td>Schritt</td><td>Startwert" + a + "</td><td>Fehler</td></tr>"));

 for(var i=1;i<zeilen+1;i++) {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("<tr>"));
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("<td>i</td>")));
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("<td>" + x_werte[i] + "</td>"));
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("<td>" + errors[i] + "</td>"));
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("</tr>)));
 }
 document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("</table>"));
 document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Ergebnis: Wurzel von" + a + "ist" + ergbenis + "(approximiert)"));
}
}
newtonRoot(1);
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
 </html>
```

But it seems not to be working?
I tried validating it using http://www.jslint.com/, but there were so many little things marked as errors and getting rid of them brought me the error:

> "Expected '(end)' and instead saw < !DOCTYPE html >"

which seems to be a bug.
Another site actually found no errors, so what did I do wrong here?

I even used this appendChild instead of write because as I understood it, write can only be used on pageload.

**Edit:**   Ok maybe I didn't make my initial goal clear:
**I want to create a table in HTML, but not by writing the code into the body, but rather let the script write it with the for loop.**

Comment: It sounds like you pasted the entire HTML into JSLint; don't do that. Only enter the JavaScript.

Comment: @MattBall Ok thank you for clarification, but now I get "'document' was used before it was defined" but I can't really define it, can i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Missing opening HTML and HEAD tags. Missing title tag.
2. Lots of syntax errors in code
3. be careful of using the const. its not widely supported. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Here is the cleaned up code :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function nextStep(xn, a) {
            var xn1 = (xn + (a / xn) / 2);
            return xn1;
        }

        function getError(xn, a) {
            var err = xn - (a / xn);
            return err;
        }

        function newtonRoot(x) {
            if (x > 0) {
                var a = 2;
                var error = getError(x, a);
                var zeilen = 5;
                var x_werte = [];
                var errors = [];

                while (error > 0.0001) {
                    x = nextStep(x, a);
                    error = getError(x, a);
                    zeilen++;
                    x_werte[zeilen] = x;
                    errors[zeilen] = error;
                }
                var ergebnis = x;
                var GLOBAL_ERROR = error;

                var table = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("table"));
                table.setAttribute('border', '1');
                var hrow = document.createElement('tr');
                var td1 = document.createElement('td'); td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Schritt"));
                var td2 = document.createElement('td'); td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Startwert " + a));
                var td3 = document.createElement('td'); td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Fehler"));
                hrow.appendChild(td1); hrow.appendChild(td2); hrow.appendChild(td3);
                table.appendChild(hrow);

                for (var i = 1; i < zeilen + 1; i++) {
                    var row = document.createElement('tr');
                    var td_i = document.createElement('td'); td_i.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
                    var td_x_werte = document.createElement('td'); td_x_werte.appendChild(document.createTextNode(x_werte[i]));
                    var td_errors = document.createElement('td'); td_errors.appendChild(document.createTextNode(errors[i]));
                    row.appendChild(td_i); row.appendChild(td_x_werte); row.appendChild(td_errors);
                    table.appendChild(row);
                }
                document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Ergebnis: Wurzel von " + a + " ist " + ergebnis + " (approximiert)"));
            }
        }
        newtonRoot(1);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not, it says "var ergebnis = x;" how can i define it more

Comment: Well thanks but my issue still remains, it doesnt work at all.
I am trying to create a HTML table, but not by writing the HTML code into the body, but by letting the script write it, but that doesn't seem to work, can you help me with that?

Comment: the revised code builds the table properly for you. now fix your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Error:

```
if(x>0 {
```

must be

```
if(x > 0) {
```

Comment: OK i changed that, but that didnt seem to be the major problem

Comment: So what is the major problem? What error message do you get? Open Google Chrome and press F12, this will show you any errors

Comment: Well that it doesnt work at all, the page is blank when I open it

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of errors in this code.  I think I have it [working in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisP/4t5pW/), but I'm not sure what the end goal is.  JSHint shows multiple small mistakes, and you should fix them rather than writing them off as not relevant.

Here are my fixes:

```
function nextStep(xn, a) {
 var xn1 = (xn+(a/xn)/2);
 return xn1;
}

function getError(xn, a) {
 var err = xn-(a/xn);
 return err;
}

function newtonRoot(x) {
if(x>0) {
 var a = 2;
 var error = getError(x, a);
 var zeilen = 0;
 var x_werte = [];
 var errors = [];

 while(error>0.0001) {
 x = nextStep(x, a);
 error = getError(x, a);
 zeilen++;
 x_werte[zeilen] = x;
 errors[zeilen] = error;
 }
 var ergebnis = x;
 var GLOBAL_ERROR = error;

 document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("<table border=" + "1" + ">"));
 document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("<tr><td>Schritt</td><td>Startwert" + a + "</td><td>Fehler</td></tr>"));

 for(var i=1;i<zeilen+1;i++) {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("<tr>"));
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("<td>i</td>"));
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("<td>" + x_werte[i] + "</td>"));
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("<td>" + errors[i] + "</td>"));
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("</tr>"));
 }
 document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("</table>"));
 document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Ergebnis: Wurzel von" + a + "ist" + ergbenis + "(approximiert)"));
}
}
newtonRoot(1);
```

Comment: My goal was to actually create a table with this, not just print it, or is this not possible?

Comment: Yes with this I wanted to add the HTML code to the body and not write it, hence I used document.body.
If this is not the right way can you post an answer how to create a HTML table in a JavaScript function?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `"` in your line number 42

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("</tr>)));
```

should be

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("</tr>")));
```

maybe that would do.